# Which screws to hang pegboard to studs in a garage?

Tags: garage, studs, pegboard

extreme noob here. I bought some pegboard 48" x 24" which I want to hang landscape across 16" gap studs in my garage (exposed).

The pegboard is 1/4 thick tempered (Tempered hardwood 1/4 in. commercial grade pegboard.

The how to videos I've watched largely focus on drywall or furring strips. From what I can gather the recommendation is 3/4 wood screws. It just seems to me that they'd be too short? Does anyone have any experience in this area? Thanks!

Comment: 3/4 should hold the pegboard to the wall, but not much weight added to it.  1 and 1/2 inch should do well.

Answer (score 3):

3/4" is probably enough if you use multiple screws per stud.

I would go for at least a 1-1/4" truss head screw so that the heads have some holding power. A regular screw's convex head lends itself to ripping through the pegboard once enough weight is added.

In either case I think the pegboard material will fail well before the screw does.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can see the studs, you can use really long screws (no fear of hitting wires or pipes). 1-1/2" - 1/4" for the pegboard + 1-1/4" into the studs - should be plenty strong enough, but you could go for 2" if you like. 3/4" would be enough to hold the pegboard, but then I'd worry if you start hanging heavy tools on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use #8 by 1". Mine is hung with drywall screws #8 x 1, my wood screws are brass which is much softer. I placed them about every 8" vertically and 16" horizontally. If you are worried about it pulling out put construction glue on the studs before the pegboard.